# Reading all words inside a text file using a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying a way to read a .txt file inside a function. My problem is that it seems you can't use a for loop inside a function because of the return value and the only way I could think of is while loop but I'm having a problem understanding it.

Inside of my .txt contains a sentences that looks like this

```
#.txt file
This is a sample sentence . 

This is a another sample sentence .
```

I have tried list comprehension but it stores it inside a list. It's easy to read the .txt using for loop but I want to practice using function. This is my progress so far

```
def read():
    return open ('test.txt','r').read();

def sentence()
    while True:
```

The output that i want is:

```
This
is
a
sample
sentence
.

This
is
a
another
sample
sentence
.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

Use `join` to add the newlines and `split` to add those newlines to each word

```
def words_in_file(file):
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        return f.read().split()
words = words_in_file('test.txt')
print(words)
```

This prints:

```
This
is
a
sample
sentence
.
This
is
a
another
sample
sentence
.
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what your convention is for delimiting sentences (i.e. separating each sentence from the next) in your file.  From your example,  I'm going to *guess* that your rule for separating sentences might be "any amount of whitespace that includes at least one newline". (But it might equally plausibly be "exactly two newlines" or  "a period followed by zero or more whitespace characters, which may or may not include newlines".)

On that assumption, here's a simple listing that outputs things the way you want:

```
fullText = open('test.txt', 'rt').read()
for sentence in fullText.split('\n'):
    if not sentence.strip():
        continue     # if what we've got is just a blank (or whitespace-only) line, then skip it
    for word in sentence.split():
        print(word)
    print('')  # blank line between sentences
```

You mentioned that you had tried list comprehensions: keep using them! They're often the most flexible and maintainable way to do this kind of thing.  They won't prevent you from doing what you want—sure, you get the results in a `list` which is only an *intermediate* step towards the kind of output you want, but it's a useful representation.  What matters is what you do next with it (iterate over the list and print each element presumably—or perhaps `'\n'.join()` the list together and just print the result once).

The answer changes if your source text file is, or might become, very large. In that case, you probably don't want to `.read()` it all in in one go and manipulate it in memory.  One thing you can do instead is actually to use the file-handle object itself as an iterator, to obtain one line at a time:

```
with open('test.txt', 'rt') as file_handle:
    for line in file_handle:
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        for word in line.split():
            print(word)
        print('')
```

The approach changes again if your rule for delimiting sentences is more complicated (like the "period followed by zero or more whitespace characters" rule). Then you should read up on **regular expressions** and the `re` module (`re.split()` would be useful—but only really efficient or easy-to-use if you're working on a small-ish file that has been slurped into memory).